# Python: Reading file: Prevent escaping special character

Tags: python, special-characters

I'm reading from a file which contains:
`this is the first line\n this is the second line\n\nAnother line`

I'm trying to read this file and keeping the special characters `\n` as they are.

```
with open(r'test.txt') as f:
    c = f.read()
```

But printing `c` shows always:

`this is the first line\\n this is the second line\\n\\nAnother line`

I've tried without prefixing with `r` in `r'text.txt'` but it doesn't change anything.

Is it possible to prevent escaping the special character `\n`?

I could do a `str.replace('\\n','\n')` of course, but I was just wondering whether we could do without this extra step.

Comment: Does your file contain literally "\n" or does it contain a newline? Are you really printing it? Printing should not escape characters, opposed to repr.

Comment: `c = f.readlines()` to maintain the file's structure? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: printing it on the interface as an output will not show \n on the screen. `print c`. If you try to see that as raw input then it will pop up anyway. The Best you can do to avoid such thing is `import re ; re.sub('\s+', ' ',c)`

Comment: ``\\n\n`` in the output you posted, it is strange that the first backslash is escaped and the second one not. Anyway, I just tested your example in a python console in Windows (with an ANSI test.txt without any line feeds or carriage returns) and ``print c`` did not escape any characters.

Comment: `'text.txt'` and `r'text.txt'` are EXACTLY THE SAME STRING - the 'r' prefix only affects interpretation of escape characters within the string, of which there are none here.  It can hardly affect the contents of the file data you read later, in any case.

Comment: I don't need to print the output. I just want to store it in a variable. I've tried `c = f.readlines()` but it's still escaping.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 scenarios:

1. You are reading it on windows in text mode using Python 2. Windows is using `\r\n` and Python 2 in text mode is thus expecting `\r\n`. You should enable universal newline mode by adding `U`, `open('file.txt', 'rU')`. You can also use `io.open` instead of `open`. I don't have Python 2 so I haven't tried it...
2. You literally have two characters `\` and `n` in your file and not a newline in which case everything is behaving as expected.